# jenkins Could not set the value of environment variable 'BUILD_USER'

Tags: jenkins, build

i'm using jenkins to build android project, 
however i always got below error: "* What went wrong:Could not set the value of environment variable 'BUILD_USER': could not convert string to current locale"
i don't know where is environment variable 'BUILD_USER',i am confused why could not set it. can anyone please help?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BUILD_USER comes from the Build User Vars plugin. It should be the First and Last name of the user who triggered the build (as defined in the Security Realm, i.e. LDAP, internal DB, etc.).

I am guessing that there is some character in the name of the user that doesn't agree with the locale configured in your Jenkins environment. You could disabled that plugin (remove the checkbox next to it in the "Manage Plugins" page), and see if the error goes away. Then you can troubleshoot from there.